# d3 create SVG path from array

Tags: svg, d3.js

Following this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/4xXQT/
I was able to render the points coordinates stored in one array using D3 as follow
https://jsfiddle.net/il_pres/qq9o1ovt/.

```
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", 30)
     .attr("height", 30);
var regioni = [{regione:'Abruzzo',polygon:{points:'25.171,18.844 25.094,18.582 24.567,17.714 24.015,17.714 23.226,16.899 22.805,16.268 21.911,14.558 21.043,14.427 20.753,15.163 20.043,15.084 19.938,15.741 19.386,16.268 19.386,17.056 18.439,16.899 18.202,17.345 18.334,17.924 18.281,18.582 19.57,19.423 18.939,20.055 18.176,19.581 17.756,20.16 17.808,20.844 18.703,21.08 19.517,21.396 19.491,22.079 20.517,22.185 20.596,22.605 21.122,22.133 21.832,22.658 22.568,22.737 23.094,23.473 23.646,22.553 23.751,21.738 24.646,21.212 25.094,21.738 25.409,22.29 26.25,21.238 26.409,20.475 26.776,19.923 26.303,19.634 26.145,19.292'}},{regione:'Basilicata',polygon:{points:'24.607,15.268 23.476,14.716 23.818,14.4 23.161,13.848 22.556,14.111 22.135,14.005 21.529,14.452 20.53,14.716 19.294,14.111 18.952,13.742 18.426,14.242 18.479,14.926 17.637,14.321 17.295,14.531 17.479,15.426 16.611,16.083 17.216,16.451 17.637,17.556 18.321,18.214 18.453,18.792 19.189,18.871 19.61,18.424 20.662,19.186 20.662,19.581 20.109,19.844 19.978,20.344 20.662,20.081 21.188,20.318 21.372,20.002 21.951,19.713 22.424,19.713 22.949,20.265 23.423,20.896 23.555,21.448 23.187,22.053 23.213,22.658 23.844,23.027 24.475,23.105 25.159,23.605 25.08,23.894 25.58,24.157 26.158,24.157 26.5,23.552 27.105,23.552 27.631,22.816 27.92,22.238 27.579,21.291 26.658,20.475 26.132,19.844 26.053,19.239 25.238,18.45 25.238,17.766 26.001,17.74 26.264,17.398 26.21,16.609 25.764,16.32 24.712,16.136'}}];
vis.selectAll("polygon")
.data(regioni) .enter().append("polygon")
.attr("points",function(d) {return d.polygon.points})
.attr("stroke","red")
.attr("stroke-width",0.1);
```

Now I was trying to do the same with the same svg shape, this time stored as d coordinates

```
var regionico =[{Regione:'Abruzzo',polygon:{points:'m 127.945,84.9805 -0.781,2.6172 -5.273,8.6835 -5.508,0 -7.891,8.1528 -4.219,6.308 -8.9292,17.09 -8.6836,1.32 -2.8985,-7.363 -7.1015,0.789 -1.0547,-6.57 -5.5157,-5.266 0,-7.89 -9.4648,1.582 -2.3711,-4.4731 1.3164,-5.7812 -0.5273,-6.582 12.8906,-8.4063 -6.3086,-6.3203 -7.6367,4.7383 -4.1992,-5.793 0.5273,-6.8359 8.9453,-2.3633 8.1445,-3.1641 -0.2617,-6.8242 10.2617,-1.0664 0.7813,-4.1992 5.2656,4.7265 7.0977,-5.2539 7.3632,-0.7812 5.25,-7.3633 5.527,9.1992 1.055,8.1446 8.945,5.2656 4.473,-5.2656 3.164,-5.5157 8.399,10.5157 1.601,7.6367 3.652,5.5195 -4.726,2.8906 -1.582,3.418 -9.727,4.4805'}},{Regione:'Basilicata',polygon:{points:'m 123.746,104.57 -7.637,-4.7458 -9.453,3.4178 -3.961,8.692 -12.3512,2.089 2.1093,9.739 -7.6289,4.734 -5,-5.516 -6.0547,3.418 -7.3633,-7.109 0.5274,-7.891 -2.6172,-3.41 -7.6367,-0.527 0,-6.57 8.1445,-7.9027 0.8008,-6.0352 5.2539,-6.3281 9.4727,-8.1445 3.4101,-9.4727 -3.1562,-6.0547 -5,-7.0898 5.2617,-5.2617 2.1094,-5.2539 2.8906,6.8242 8.9375,0.8008 3.4375,-7.625 16.8128,4.207 3.945,14.9805 12.109,-1.0547 9.981,23.4101 -9.727,5.7891 0,14.4723 -7.617,3.418'}}
```

but if I use the same code with d as attr.

```
vis.selectAll("path")
.data(regionico).enter().append("path")
.attr("d",function(d) { return d.polygon.points})
.attr("stroke","red")
.attr("stroke-width",0.1);
```

it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Works fine, you just need to make the SVG bigger: https://jsfiddle.net/qq9o1ovt/3/

Comment: I've posted the link to the working fiddle above.

Comment: Thanxs, now it's seems to work...

Comment: Sorry Lars...I' m fresh new of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that your SVG isn't big enough to make the `path` visible -- note in particular how you're first moving more than 100 pixels to the right before starting the path. It works fine if you make the SVG bigger, e.g. 300x300 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qq9o1ovt/3/).